# Save image (print screen) to FTP error?

Tags: c#, ftp, screenshot

Im trying to make a really simple app, to save the current screen to an FTP directory.

It is with a timer set to 5-10 seconds(it must be enough for that...) :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = int.Parse(textBox4.Text)*1000;
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
    int posx = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int posy = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(posx, posy, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

    printscreen.Save(@"C:\Teszt\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://neo-inv.com/" + "/public_html/filename.jpg");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "xxxx");
    request.UseBinary = true;
    printscreen.Save(request.GetRequestStream(), ImageFormat.Png);

}
```

I'm getting error:

> WebException was unhandled 
>   Exception:Caught:The operation has timed out.
>   Excepton:Thrown:The operation has timed out.

First timer cycle is OK, second or third is always this exception. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You didn't close the request, call request.close()

Comment: It doesnt work. cant compile, there is no request.close method.

Answer (score 0):

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://neo-inv.com/" + "/public_html/filename.jpg");
```

wouldnt this try to create an ftp request to ftp://neo-inv.com//public_html/filename.jpg.
The double forward slash may be what is giving you issues.

Comment: can you access the ftp site with filezilla or whatever ftp client you use?